# JSF/Richfaces partial table render with subtable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Is partially rendering a single column in a collapsibleSubTable using @rows in RichFaces 4 possible?

For example this works with a single datatable.

```
List<Integer> updatedRows
render="myForm:myTable:@rows(updatedRows):id"
```

I'm not sure how to do this dynamically With a collapsibleSubTable.

```
render="myForm:myTable:@rows(updatedRows):mySub:@rows(updatedSubRows):id
```

Is it possible to pass the current iteration of updatedRows into updatedSubRows?  Something along the lines of.

```
render="myForm:myTable:@rows(updatedRows):mySub:@rows(updatedSubRows(currentUpdatedRow)):id
```

Where currentUpdatedRow is updatedRows[0], updatedRows[1] and so on.

Or maybe using a `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>()`?